# How to only allow Windows built-in VPN connection and block Internet access when it's not connected?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, dns, firewall

I've read many related questions in this website but none of them were unfortunately 100% helpful for my situation, but they got me all the way to this point.

I have a VPN connection set up in Windows 10 settings. I do not have it's IP address, I only have its domain name. so I basically only have domain name + username + password and it uses PPTP/L2TP protocols.

**I set my VPN connection location to Public.**

**set my WiFi connection location to Private.**

in Windows Firewall, created a rule and blocked all outbound connections for domain + private network locations. (left out Public, which is the location of my VPN connection)

then in the same outbound section of Firewall, made an allow rule for this program:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe
```

and this one:

```
C:\windows\system32\rasdial.exe
```

and also made a 3nd allow rule for this port: `UDP 53`, (DNS lookup).

so despite doing all of that, I still can't connect to my VPN connection. what am I missing here?

Comment: See this question>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1590521/configuring-windows-to-only-allow-traffic-through-vpn/1590570

Comment: @Moab but like i mentioned i dont have IP address of the VPN, i use host name because the IP address of the VPN server changes regularly. can't use the solution there. why can't anyone help me correctly identify the right component and make an allow rule for it in Firewall? i've seen lots of harder problems answered here.